# MicrosoftAzureMobile.MSClient.loginWithProvider with provider and token failed with return Code=-1505 "The token provided was not valid

Tags: facebook, azure

There

I'm using MicrosoftAzureMobile ios framework to connect to an azure mobile app with authentication enabled. I configured the service with facebook login. I can successfully login with FBSDKLogin as well as MicrosoftAzureMobile.MSClient.loginWithProvider with provider and controller. However when I try the loginwithProvider with token get from FBSDK, 
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
          client.loginWithProvider("facebook", token: ["access_token":accessToken]){

I got below error

MicrosoftAzureMobile.MSClient.loginWithProvider with provider and token failed with return Code=-1505 "The token provided was not valid.

how do I debug this issue? the azure portal's tools/streaming logs works last week but always shows connecting today

thanks
Joe

problem solved, i have to use accessToken.tokenString because accessToken itself is not serializable to json

Comment: problem solved, turns out you need to use accessToken.tokenString because accessToken itself is not serializable to json